# NSViewController subclass troubles

Tags: objective-c, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

I have created a `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass, called `TSCollectionViewController`. It overrides *one* method, `setRepresentedObject:`. I plan on using it in my `NSView`, `TSTopChartView`. Oddly enough, I get an error when I add it to the `TSTopChartView.h` file (pictured below). 
[image]
[image]

Obviously, Xcode doesn't like `TSCollectionViewController` for this file. I just can't figure out why! I've imported the file, so it shouldn't be an unknown type name. Any ideas? Thank you for your time!

Here is TSCollectionViewController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TSTopChartCell.h"
#import "TSPodcastEpisodeCell.h"
#import "TSDetailView.h"

@interface TSCollectionViewController : NSCollectionViewItem
@end
```

Comment: Would help to see TSCollectionViewController.h.

Comment: There's nothing interesting in the .h file. I simply import a few files. None the less, Nevertheless, I've updated the post with the code.

Comment: Have clean and rebuild the project? and You need to redsing your project as well, It is a bad practise to have controller inside a View class :) A controller should have reference to Views and Model.

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize that. Thanks for pointing that out! I'm still learning this stuff ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular #import dependency between TSCollectionViewController.h and TSTopChartView.h. In your case you can break it easily by removing `#import "TSTopChartCell.h"` from TSCollectionViewController.h.

If you end up in a case where you really need the class `TSTopChartCell` to be declared in TSCollectionViewController.h you can fix this by adding `@class TSTopChartCell` instead of the `#import "TSTopChartCell.h"`. Then you can actually `#import "TSTopChartCell.h"` in the implementation file, TSCollectionViewController.m.